# How to write tagged string into text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, textblob

I am using POS tagging, parse chunking and deep parsing in one step using TextBlob. I want to write the output in a txt file. The error I get is 
"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'TaggedString'"

Following is the code I am using. The out variable contains information like this. 
 Technique:Plain/NNP/B-NP/O and/CC/I-NP/O enhanced-MPR/JJ/I-NP/O CT/NN/I-NP/O chest/NN/I-NP/O is/VBZ/B-VP/O
[image]

```
 from textblob import TextBlob
 with open('report1to8_1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    report=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

 out = TextBlob(report).parse()
 tagS = 'taggedop.txt'
 f = open('taggedop.txt', 'wb')
 f.write(out)
```

I also want to split these tags into dataframe in this way.
[image]

Comment: Try with `f.write(bytes(out))` or with `f.write(str(out))`

Comment: Or, if `out` can be iterated on, loop on its elements and write each to the file.  BTW why openin it as binary? And remember to close it afterwards  (or open it in a `with` statement)